# How do I merge two stackoverflow accounts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

How do I merge two stackoverflow accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Flag one of your questions or answers for moderator attention, and ask for the accounts to be merged.

Make sure you are clear *which account you want to keep.*

Also note that we cannot merge registered accounts into unregistered ones, so this works better if the master account (the one you want to keep) is a registered account.

Make sure that the *email addresses for both accounts are identical.*  This is how we prove that the two accounts belong to the same person.

Comment: I"m getting the following error message when I try to set the same email address "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
Email is already registered"

Comment: @Henry: Must be because you didn't use OpenID. Did you flag?

Comment: Is this how I would flag?

Comment: @Henry: Do you see the "flag" link above this, right below my answer. where it says `mod|link|edit|delete|flag? ` Click that link, on one of your questions or answers.